# NodeJs - async function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making an api in NodeJs and I have a function that I call through the post, but before forwarding to the precise repository I run the function `getProduct (idProd, product)`, but is doing `console.log ('product ->' + product.name);` before running the `getProduct (idProd, product)` function. I do not know how to make it wait for the other function to finish. I already tried adding **async** and **await**, but without success

```
exports.postItemProduto = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        var idProd = req.body.produtoPrincipal;

        await getProduto(idProd, produto);

        console.log('produto -> '+ produto.nome);
        itemService.insertItem(req, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(412).send({
                success: false
            });
        }
        return res.send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Item registado com sucesso!'
        });
    }) 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Erro criar item'
        });
    };
};

function getProduto(id, produto){
    var url = 'url/api/produtos/'+id;
axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
            /* let produto = new ProductDto(); */
            produto.produtoId = response.data.productId;
            produto.nome =  response.data.nome;
            produto.descricao = response.data.descricao;
            produto.material_AcabamentoID = response.data.material_AcabamentoID;
            produto.restrictionId = response.data.restrictionId;
                /* let restriction = new RestrictionDto();
                restriction = getRestriction(jsonData[i].restrictionId); */
            console.log('produto -->' + produto.nome);


    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Put that translation **in the question** - anyway, `getProduto` would need to return something for a start, and if you expect to `await` it, then it should return a **Promise** - because that what `await` waits for, Promises to resolve

Comment: produto is global variable. i don't how to do **Promise** in this case

Comment: since you've shown nothing about what it does (except for a console.log), then I doubt anyone could help

Comment: I updated the code,in this moment, i just need **produto** object, all the functions are working, but i can't get the **produto** on **exports.postItemProduto**

Comment: Is this the complete code? Before calling await getProduto(idProd, produto); there's no produto anywhere... Anyway moving towards await and async functions: check this: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: i resolve the problem with getProduto(idProd, function(produto) {
                console.log('produto -> ' + produto.nome); 
        });

Comment: of course, mixing Promises (which you do have in `axios.get().then()` with callbacks is not recommended ... all you had to do was `return axios...rest of your existing code` and that would've been enough - because you'd be returning a Promise, that you can `await`

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.postItemProduto = function (req, res) {
    try {
        var idProd = req.body.produtoPrincipal;
        console.log('id --> ' + idProd);

        getProduto(idProd, function(produto) {
                console.log('produto -> ' + produto.nome); 
        });


         itemService.insertItem(req, function (err) {
             if (err) {
                 return res.status(412).send({
                     success: false
                 });
             }
             return res.send({
                 success: true,
                 message: 'Item registado com sucesso!'
             });
         }) 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Erro criar item'
        });
    };
};

function getProduto(id, callback) {
    var url = 'url/api/produtos/' + id;
    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(response => {
            /* let produto = new ProductDto(); */
            produto.produtoId = response.data.productId;
            produto.nome = response.data.nome;
            produto.descricao = response.data.descricao;
            produto.material_AcabamentoID = response.data.material_AcabamentoID;
            produto.restrictionId = response.data.restrictionId;
            /* let restriction = new RestrictionDto();
            restriction = getRestriction(jsonData[i].restrictionId); */
            callback(produto);

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```